# How to verify-: A language over Σ is also a language over any alphabet that is a superset of Σ?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, proof-techniques

Context-:

A language over Σ need not include strings with all symbols of Σ Thus, a language over Σ is also a language over any alphabet that is a superset of Σ.

https://www.univ-orleans.fr/lifo/Members/Mirian.Halfeld/Cours/TLComp/TLComp-introTL.pdf

Page number 10

**I am trying to understand what it is trying to say-:**

Σ={a,b}

1. Language need not include both a,b. Which makes sense to me.
2. L is language over Σ={a,b} say L={aa,aaaa,aaaaaa}
3. L is language over Σ then  L is language over any alphabet which is superset of Σ.

My confusion is they say L is language over Σ and L is language over any alphabet which is superset of Σ. But isn't superset of Σ=Σ itself? So is there any sense in this logic? This seems to be written in every books I have followed. So curious if it has some deep meaning or just is theory.

As well as another confusion is how we reached this conclusion? Can you show step by step procedure that lead us to believe that if L is language over Σ, then L is language over any alphabet which is superset of Σ.(I don't need mathematical proofs, any verification techniques using examples will work good for me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Sigma$ is a (not proper) superset of itself but there are other supersets of $\Sigma$. For example if $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ and $\Sigma'=\{a,b,c\}$ then $\Sigma'$ is a (proper) superset of $\Sigma$.

To show that the claim is true you just need to show that, for every finite set $\Sigma' \supseteq \Sigma$, you have $(\Sigma')^* \supseteq \Sigma^*$. Then, for any language $L$ over $\Sigma$ you have:
$$
L \subseteq \Sigma^* \subseteq (\Sigma')^*,
$$
and hence $L$ is also a language over $\Sigma'$.

Comment: wow beautiful, exactly what I needed. Thanks a ton.